# Android swipelistview swipe only one item

Tags: android

I'm using the `swipelistview` library but what I want is to open just one item at a time,

is there a way I can do it or do I have to come up with a workarround?

Answer (score 1):

```
    mSwipeListView.setSwipeListViewListener(new com.example.swipelistview.BaseSwipeListViewListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onOpened(int position, boolean toRight) {

                        for(int i=0;i<mSwipeListView.getChildCount();i++){
                          if(i!=position)
                                mSwipeListView.closeAnimate(i);

                        }
```

try this it might work, I did not test it

Answer (score 0):

You shall use the following in the code :

```
listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
```